# Can i access data on one spark cluster from another?

Tags: apache-spark, hive

What if I want to sample a table over hive on Spark-cluster-1, but I'm logged in on Spark-cluster-2?

> `Connecting to jdbc:hive2://spark.cluster.1:10000/default;principal=hive/_HOST@US.AD.companyname.com;ssl=true`

This call returns error: "Error: Could not open client transport with JDBC Uri:" when I issue the call from spark.cluster.2 using this call:

> `hive -e "select * FROM database.tablename where rand() <= 0.0001 order by rand()  limit 10"`

What are the limitations to do this? I should be able to read a table even if I'm not logged-in to the cluster where the hive tables reside.

This doesn't make these data fluid. The current workaround is to copy them tables manually from one cluster to the other.

Is there a better way to do this?